# Value after the decimal is getting removed while consuming HANA CV in Design Studio

Tags: hana, business-objects

It's a very strange issue. I have data like this in HANA:

```
Year  columnA   ColumnB
2017   22.65     66.79
```

When I am using this Calculation View as a data source in SAP Design Studio:

edit initial view:

```
Year  columnA   ColumnB
2017   22.00     66.00
```

I am getting it like this-> values after decimal are getting removed.

In HANA, `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` are of `Decimal(10,2)` datatype.

Comment: Perchance are ColumnA and ColumnB being declared in the CV as int instead of decimal?  You say it's decimal 10,2 but you don't specify if the CV attribute has this or the table.

Comment: There's lots of places this error could be occurring between the CA_view and BO.  Is the final query being consumed by IDT (if you're using universes) Does the data type at the Aggregation node in the CV decimal(10,2)?  then what about the value in the universe?  Lastly in BO what is the datatype being defined as and have you set the format to show 2 decimals? when you edit the format in the rich client?